# Can't get write permission to file

Tags: php, file-permissions

I'm trying to save some text that comes into a php script via a POST to a file. Here is my script:

```
<?php

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$file = $path . '\test.txt';

$text = $_POST['text'];

// save it to a file
if (file_exists($file))
    chmod($file, 0777);

$handle = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($handle, $text);
fclose($handle);

echo "success";

?>
```

I'm getting this error:

> **Warning**: 
>   fopen(D:\Hosting\11347607\html\test.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream:
>   Permission denied in
>   **D:\Hosting\11347607\html\test_file_saver.php** on line
>   **12**

I've tried a number of different attempts and read many posts. The directory is set to RWX permission.  How can I get permission to write to this file? Thanks!

Comment: How can `test.txt` become `contacts.json` in this case?

Comment: `$file = $path . '/test.txt';` with paths always use `slash` not `backslash`.

Comment: @KristerAndersson Sorry about that - actual path is a little long, so I shortened it to make it easier to read. Overlooked that part. My bad.

Comment: @walkingRed I tried the slashes both ways, and I get the same result.

Comment: @usr55410 - Okej, but when you add an error message it's very important to actually add the real error message and not a made up one=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have permissions to even open the file, what makes you think you have permission to change permissions?

That wasn't a question or a comment. You don't have permission to change the permission. Give your PHP process proper permissions.

Comment: It was a server setting. I was attempting to this through FileZilla, but the settings weren't being accepted by the server. Once I made the change directly through the host software, my problem disappeared.